# Where can I find the area51 proposals for graduate sites?

Tags: support, area-51

Since the graduate proposals aren't listed in the **progress** tab, where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the links:

- [Webapps](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications)
- [Gaming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming)
- [Webmasters](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters)
- [Ubuntu](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu)
- [Cooking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking)
- [Game Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development)
- [Mathematics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics)
- [Photography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing)